# AngularFire2 - .valueChanges() does not return my data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire

I'm new with AngularFire + Firebase and I'm trying to do the tutorial from angularfire2 github.

When I do this code:

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();
}
```

And print in the console the variable this.items it's showing the sentence below as value (I've ):

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator
:
MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Object
```

My question is, where is the data from database? I've created a database with some data to do this, but nothing from the node 'items' is returned.

Thanks in advance

my firebase structure:

```
{
    "items": {
        "1": {
            "code": "C001",
            "name": "client test"
        },
        "2": {
            "code": "C002",
            "name": "client test 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

My imports:

Component:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

NgModule:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
      // data from firebase
    }),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
```

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database

---

## Resolved

It was a problem with the rxjs version. I updated to 6.2.0 version and the code worked :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't query inside constructor. Leave constructor simple and use lifecycle hooks or your own methods.

As I can see, `items` is an Observable. But you didn't subscribed to it. You need to subscribe to `items` or you can use `async` pipe in your template. The data will be resolved over time.

In your class :

```
this.db.collection("items")
  .valueChanges()
  .subscribe(res => {})
```

Or in template :

```
<some-component *ngFor="let item of items | async"></some-component>
```

Comment: I've tried this two options, but still in trouble.When use the collection I get this: "Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'AngularFireDatabase'."

And using template, I get this runtime error: Object(...) is not a function :(

Comment: @AlexSantos - Please share your imports - both for ngModule and this component. Apart from that, I would like to know whether you are using Firebase Realtime Database or Firebase Cloud Firestore? Because, for Realtime Database, you should import `AngularFireDatabase` and for Cloud Firestore, you should import `AngularFirestore`.

[https://github.com/angular/angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Answer (score 0):

try with snapshotChanges()

> What is it? - The current state of your collection. Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of DocumentChangeAction[].

```
this.db
  .collection("azucar_nacional")
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(e => {
    e.forEach(elem => {
      console.log(elem.payload.doc.data());
    });
  });
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md